# Display InfoTemplate of Graphic Object Programatically

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri

I have a graphic object which contains a symbol and an infotemplate

```
var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("Address:", "<br>  " + address);
slcGraphic = new esri.Graphic(pt, infoSymbol, attr, infoTemplate);
map.graphics.add(slcGraphic);
```

This is showing the symbol as expected but the IntoTemplate is hidden by default. It shows up only upon clicking the Symbol.

Is there a way I can also make the InfoTemplate show up by default without having to click on the Symbol?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .setTitle and .setContent methods of the InfoWindow to display a template at a specific geometry.

```js
map.infoWindow.setTitle("Mission Trails")
map.infoWindow.setContent("<strong>"+slcGraphic.attributes.HistoricName+"</strong> ");
map.infoWindow.show(slcGraphic.geometry);
```